# MongoDB - unique multikey index not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, unique-index

I have a problem with multikey indexes in MongoDB.

I have a collection named `users`, whose documents look more or less like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId(),
  "name": "John Smith",
  ...
  "votes": [
    {
      "type": "news",
      "votedObjectId": "123"
    },
    {
      "type": "blog",
      "votedObjectId": "124"
    },
    {
      "type": "news"
      "votedObjectId": "225"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create an index on `votedObjectId` and I want users to vote only once for each article.

I ensured a unique index *(code is in node.js - mongoskin module)*:

```
`this.ensureIndex({'votes.votedObjectId': 1}, {unique: true}, ...)`
```

Then I tried voting twice for the same article, and it actually added the exact same vote twice.

How can I ensure that the array will not contain duplicate elements?

P.S.

I do all inserts with {safe: true}, and the duplicate values I get are not returned by an insert operation, but actually inserted in the collection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The {unique: true} only guarantees uniqueness across objects, it does NOT guarantee uniqueness of the array elements inside the array.

But check out the [addToSet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$addToSetand$each) functionality of mongodb.

Also this very similar question here. [How to ensure unique item in an array based on specific fields - mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383143/how-to-ensure-unique-item-in-an-array-based-on-specific-fields-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks. Program-level uniqueness check + $addToSet instead of $push seems to be the best solution in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
this.ensureIndex({'votes.votedObjectId': 1, _id: 1}, {unique: true}, ...)
```

or process voting with

```
this.update( 
  { _id:... , 'votes.votedObjectId':{$ne:'...'} }, 
  { $push: { votes: '...' }}
)
```

Hopefully, theese statements might help you to sort it out.