# Persisting only unique values in a Mongo collection -- sub arrays

Tags: java, mongodb, database

```
--- Business
   --- Sub-Business
      --- Organization Group
```

I have a data structure like this that I want to persist into Mongo.
I do not want to persist duplicate sub-businesses and I don't want to persist duplicate Organization Groups. I'm using the Business as the "_id" so there will not be any duplicates there.

These are two classes, persist is in one class and the other methods are in another. I mean the code, works but its not giving my multiple groups.

I may not understand Mongo/Java too well to get it to do what I want.

Here is what I have

```
   public void persist(Business business) {
        DB db = pool.getConnection();
        LOG.info("Business toString: " + business.toString()); // REMOVE AFTER
        try {
            db.requestStart();
            DBObject dbObjSetColumns = writeConverter.convert(business);

            DBCollection dbCol = db.getCollection(BUSINESS_COLLECTION);

            DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set",dbObjSetColumns);
            DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", business.getName());
            LOG.debug(query.toString());
            LOG.debug(update.toString());
            dbCol.update(query, update, true, false);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } finally {
            if (db != null) {
                db.requestDone();
            }
        }
   }

   public DBObject convert(Business business) {

      if (business == null) {
            return null;
        }

        final DBObject dbObj = new BasicDBObject();
        this.addSubBusinesses(business,dbObj);

        return dbObj;
      }

      private void addSubBusinesses(Business b, DBObject dbObj){
            BasicDBObject subBusiness = new BasicDBObject();
            for(SubBusiness sub : b.getSubBusinesses()){
                  subBusiness.put("name", sub.getName());
                  if(sub.getGroups() != null){
                        this.addGroupsForSubBusiness(sub, subBusiness);
                  }
            }
            dbObj.put("subBusiness", subBusiness);
      }

      private void addGroupsForSubBusiness(SubBusiness sub, DBObject dbObj){
            BasicDBList groups = new BasicDBList();
            final DBObject dbGroupObj = new BasicDBObject();
            dbGroupObj.put("group", sub.getName());
            groups.add(dbGroupObj);
            dbObj.put("groups", groups);
      }
```

Here is what I'm receiving. Fortunately it doesn't seem to be duplicating the subBusiness, but I do have multiple groups, that is not showing up here.

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : "ABC",
  "subBusiness" : {
    "name" : "subBus",
    "groups" : [{
        "group" : "Ground"
      }]
  }
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : "XYZ",
  "subBusiness" : {
    "name" : "Sub2",
    "groups" : [{
        "group" : "Air"
      }]
  }
}
```

To put it in perspective on how this works,

We persist one Business Object, that has one Sub-Business and one Group. The database may already know about the Business object, if that is the case then we do not save it twice. The same logic applies for sub business and group. The collection should only show us the unique business information.

Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide. I've been running in circles for a day now trying to get this *seemingly* easy task done.

Everything except for the addSubBusiness and addGroupForSubBusiness methods were already present, I'm just working on adding this new part, so I am refactoring this to meet my needs.

Comment: Just a question -- you state that you persist one Business Object, that has one Sub-Business and One Group. Is that the desired behavior or what it currently does?  So, if Business = "ABC", and it has 2 subBusinesses, "Sub1" and "Sub2", do you want to persist two documents { _id: "ABC", subBusiness: { name: "Sub1", groups: ...} } and { _id: "ABC", subBusiness: { name: "Sub2", groups: ... } } or a single document { _id: "ABC", subBusiness: [ { name: "Sub1", ...}, { name: "Sub2", ... } ] }?  For adding unique elements to an array, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/

Comment: Also, in your addGroupsForSubBusiness method, should you not be looping through the groups in your sub object, and adding to the list, instead of just adding initializing a group object with ?subBusiness name? dbGroupObj.put("group", sub.getName()); and adding just that one group to the groups list?

Comment: We want a single document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your classes, but it does seem like your addGroupsForSubBusiness method needs to change to something like:

```
 private void addGroupsForSubBusiness(SubBusiness sub, DBObject dbObj){
        BasicDBList groups = new BasicDBList();

        for (Group group: sub.getGroups()) {
            DBObject dbGroupObj = new BasicDBObject();
            dbGroupObj.put("group", group.getName());
            groups.add(dbGroupObj);
        }

        dbObj.put("groups", groups);
  }

}
```

Similar change in your subBusiness method since as you currently have it, your method loops through the subBusinesses for your Business, but only adds one object, the last subBusiness, at end.

Will you also persist only once for the Business?  Or could you call persist multiple times for a Business, as in first time for a Business "ABC", with a subBusiness "sub1", and then another time for Business "ABC", and subBusiness "sub2", in which case, you want to append to an existing document. If your Business object is complete (as in the object contains all its subBusinesses and Groups when you call persist), then I think the method changes mentioned above should help.  Also, you can use the save() method since your determining existence on the _id field.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Answer (score 0):

If you require only one sub-business and one group, then you would be better off restructuring your document to something like this:

```
{_id:"business_val", sub_business:"sub_business_val", group:"group_val"}
```

Your code should look like:

```
new BasicDBObject().append("_id", "business_val").append("sub_business", "sub_business_val").append("group", "group_val");
```

Additionally, you need to ensure unique index on the collection using:

```
db.[your_collection].ensureIndex({_id:1,sub_business:1,group:1},{unique:true})
```

Comment: There can be many sub businesses under a business. There can also be many groups under a sub business. I think we wanted to keep each business in one document.

Comment: There is a known issue wherein unique constraints cannot be enforced on array. You'll have to do it manually while adding elements to your document. Refer below URL for workaround to your problem.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383143/how-to-ensure-unique-item-in-an-array-based-on-specific-fields-mongodb]

Comment: Bah, I'm still having trouble with this. I would gladly give someone 100 reputation to help me out with this (would give more but I don't have much). I feel like I've changed and modified this code but still can't get to my desired outcome. :(