# How do I ensure uniqueness in an array of subdocuments in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents with the following structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("531db35c4e08d754e036d4c1"),
"name" : "Group 1",
"description" : "First group",
"recipients" : [
    {
        "cellnumber" : "27123456789",
    },
    {
        "cellnumber" : "27987654321",
    },
    {
        "cellnumber" : "27837939043",
    }
],
"creationdate" : NumberLong("1394455388960"),
"accountKey" : "B6D45025BFDC5D2D1E5FA158A2729FCC"
}
```

I have a requirement that the each recipient in the group document be uniquely identified by the cellnumber. However, multiple groups can have the same recipient. How do I ensure that each group has a recipient subdocument where each recipient is unique.
Here is what I tried by way of ensureIndex

```
> db.groups.ensureIndex({"name":1, "recipients.cellnumber":1}, {unique:true})
```

That did not seem to work as additions of recipients with already existing numbers went through without errors.
Is it even possible to uniquely index a subdocument array?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383143/how-to-ensure-unique-item-in-an-array-based-on-specific-fields-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator which you can use when [updating](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) elements in an array (set) that may be worth looking into. In your case you would use it like this:

```js
db.groups.update({
    $addToset: { "receipients": { "cellnumber": "27123456789" } }
})
```

And that will make sure that the values in the recipients field, as long as they **all** are just keyed by `cellnumber` will all be unique.

Outside of this you are managing this in code.