# MongoDB Validator on Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, validation

Lets say I've got an Events collection that has documents that look like this:

```
{
  name: "myevent",
  invitees: [ 
    {
      name: "mike",
      bff_level: 3
    },
    {
      name: "michelle",
      bff_level: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to enforce that no single Events document includes two `invitees` with the same `name`. Can that be done using [MongoDB document validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), i.e. that `invitees` are unique by `name` within a document. Am I stuck managing this at the application level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure unique item in an array based on specific fields - mongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383143/how-to-ensure-unique-item-in-an-array-based-on-specific-fields-mongodb)

Comment: @bureaquete I'm not sure it *is* a duplicate, but perhaps I'm wrong. Also that was asked 5 years ago... so maybe there is new information available for MongoDB 3.4

Comment: I understand your point, but see the latest comments on the answer, it was answered couple months ago, saying that the issue is still not fixed. That is why I chose to flag as duplicate.

Comment: If the entire array element must not be duplicated (i.e. the bff_level field is going to be the same for guest in both entries) then it can be done as of 3.6 with $jsonSchema document validation feature